# JTA timeout when sending multiple mails

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, jakarta-mail

Thousand of mails are to be sended in a **for** loop. After sending some of mails I get JTA timeout error.

Local mail server config:

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=****
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
```

Weblogic has 30 seconds JTA timeout and increasing timeout is not an option.

Things that I have tried:

- Sending mails in async method
- Thread.sleep when certain amount of mails are sent.

I think, I need to reset connection for every mail or something like that but I do not know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the question is if it is really necessary to run the mail sending logic within a **single** JTA transaction? Couldn't the mail sending logic be split up into multiple transactions?

Comment: Sending mail isn't transactional.  You can't roll back an earlier send if a later end fails.

Comment: Do you suggest JMS in that case? @AndreSteingress